# Backbone router - Replace whitespace

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a problem with replace whitespace on the url with the Backbone Router.

I searched the solution in the internet but i can't resolve this problem.

I need that if the users when enter in my site with the next url, for example: "[http://www.example.com/example example](http://www.example.com/example%20example)", the router must replace the whitespace with "+" or "-" character. i.e. the url must be "http://www.example.com/example+example" or "http://www.example.com/example-example".

Thank you

Comment: That's not a valid URL, the browser should be converting it to `http://www.example.com/example%20example` before the router has a chance to do anything. Where are these broken URLs coming from?

Comment: I need to know if you can capture the whitespace or "%20" for transform URL to friendly URL. In my browser not converted the whitespace to %20, but It is possible that is about the version browser ?

Comment: Just because it looks like a space in the URL bar doesn't mean that it isn't really `%20`. Have you checked what `window.location` really is?

Comment: Yes, i checked with `window.location` and i see URL with whitespace and my browser not converted the whitespace to %20.

`window.location.href` shows `http://www.example.com/example example`